# Are all Debian 11 systems automatically vulnerable to CVE-2023-38408?

Tags: debian, openssh, sshd, vulnerability

I really really hope I'm wrong here, but it seems that Debian 11 has a vulnerable version of OpenSSH.

My OpenSSH banner reports my OpenSSH version is:

`8.4p1 Debian 5+deb11u1`

I checked with sshd and it reports the same version.

According to [this](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2023-38408) CVE-2023-38408 ANY version before 9.3p2 is vulnerable.

I tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` but it did not update the OpenSSH version..

Comment: https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2023-38408

Comment: @IporSircer oh sweet baby Jesus, so even bookworm-stable is vulnerable??? :O

Comment: To exploit  that vulnerability, an attacker needs to control the remote host and have shell access to the client host. If you `ssh -A` to an attacker-controlled server, you already give access to all the private keys loaded into your agent to the attacker which in most cases is as bad if not worse than letting them run command as you on the local system, so it's not entirely surprising that Debian maintainers decided not to rush to backport that fix and classified it as a "Minor issue"

Comment: In general security fixes are backported, and in backports only the last part of the version number changes, and because time travel is still science fiction, anything a CVE (or anything else) says can not cover versions made after that CVE. So when a CVE says "any version before" it doesn't include versions with a lower version number that has had the fix backported, and that is how most distributions work. So you really need to look at a distribution specific tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing (17 August 2023) the page of [CVE-2023-38408 on the Debian security tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2023-38408) says that:

- Debian 10 ([buster](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/), security channel) is fixed
- Debian 10 ([buster](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/)) is vulnerable
- Debian 11 ([bullseye](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/)) is vulnerable
- Debian 12 ([bookworm](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/)) is vulnerable
- Debian 13 ([trixie](https://www.debian.org/releases/trixie/)) is fixed
- Debian Unstable ([sid](https://www.debian.org/releases/sid/)) is fixed

There is also a note saying that:

> [...]
>
> Minor issue; needs specific conditions and forwarding was always subject to caution warning
>
> [...]
>
> Exploitation requires the presence of specific libraries on the victim system.
> Remote exploitation requires that the agent was forwarded to an attacker-controlled
> system.